# Recover git repository after cloning error

Tags: git

I just managed to destroy a remote git repository, by cloning it not to my local directory, but to the remote directory itself ...

**EDIT (explanation)**: I navigated into the remote directory where the .git file exist (using git bash) and I ran the clone command in there.

The status is that the files are gone.

Is there any way to recover it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My creativity does not let me think of a scenario where what you describe is technically possible. Can you give more details of exactly what you did?

Comment: What do you mean by cloning into remote directory ?

Comment: I navigated into the remote directory where the .git file exist (using git bash) and I ran the clone command in there.

Comment: Please provide more info

Comment: Does the .git folder exist or it's also destroyed ?

Comment: The .git folder is still there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to recover the repo using a backup copy. The error cause is still unknown, but the problem is gone with this workaround.